# Using linq to get nth word from each line in a list in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

Hi I have a list of multi word strings.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("Robert is a bank manager");  
myList.Add("Alice is a cashier");  
myList.Add("Andrew is bank customer");
```

Now for each string line in myList, I wanted to get nth word. So let's say I want to retrieve even number positioned word from each string, I want to get output as:

```
var[] output = {"is", "bank", "is", "cashier", "is", "customer"};
```

I can simply use a for loop and store every nth word in the output array, but curious how to do the same using linq.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am curious how to do the same using LINQ

Give someone a fish and you feed them for a day; teach them to catch fish, blah blah blah.

What you need is a thought process for LINQ-ifying code. Here's the process I use.

The first thing I do is look at the description of the problem and think "where are the operations that are done to *every* element of a sequence?"

> for each string line in myList, I wanted to get nth word.

Ooh, there's one.

The next question is: Suppose I wanted to do that to an *individual* element of the sequence; how would I do that?  **Can I write a method that does that?**

This problem seems to break down nicely into two sub-problems:

1) Given a string, get back a sequence of words.
2) Given a sequence of things, produce a sequence of every nth thing.

We know how to do the first one: that's `Split()`.

What's the second one? Once again we have an operation where we are doing something to every element of a sequence. This time we're *filtering*, so it seems likely that we'd want to use a `Where`.

As others have noted, you can use the `Where` that takes an index for this. Let's write a helper method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeEveryNth(
    this IEnumerable<T> items,
    int n,
    int offset = 0) =>
  items.Where((item, i) => (i - offset) % n == 0);
```

(Notice something about this solution: there's nothing in there that is specific to sequences of strings, so I made it generic. Now we have a useful tool for more than just words.)

Super. Let's put the last two together:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EveryNthWord(
    this string sentence,
    int n,
    int offset = 0) =>
  sentence.Split(" ").TakeEveryNth(n, offset);
```

OK, we want to do this to every element in a list, and then concatenate the results all together. That's `SelectMany`. So the solution to your problem is:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EveryNthWord(
    this IEnumerable<string> sentences,
    int n,
    int offset = 0) =>
sentences.SelectMany(sentence => sentence.EveryNthWord(n, offset));
```

And now we have a solution to your problem:

```
var result = sentences.EveryNthWord(2, 1).ToList();
```

And we're done.

That's how you reason through the problem when you're trying to come up with a LINQ solution: **break everything up into tiny pieces and write a method for each piece that solves one problem well.**  Then combine them together with query operators.

What if we wanted to then make this all into one expression? **It is much easier to do that if you already have it broken up.**  Just combine them together:

```
var n = 2;
var offset = 1;
var result = sentences
  .SelectMany(sentence => sentence
    .Split(" ")
    .Where((item, i) => (i - offset) % n == 0))
  .ToList();
```

But frankly the code is more useful and readable if you keep it split up. Each helper method is useful in its own right, so keep them!

Comment: Great explanation about approaching the solution.

Comment: Loved the thought process!  Does this return non-printable characters such as \r or \n?

Answer (score 3):

One approach to doing this in LINQ would be the following:

```
var res = myList.Select(x => x.Split()
                              .Where((_,i) => (i + 1) % 2 == 0))
                .SelectMany(x => x);
```

This creates a list of lists of words that have been filtered via index, then flattens the list of lists down with `SelectMany` on an identity function.

As @Xiaoy312 points out in the comments, you can simplify this further by using `SelectMany` outright, resulting in the following:

```
var res = myList.SelectMany(x => x.Split().Where((_, i) => (i + 1) % 2 == 0));
```

Comment: Thumbs up for `SelectMany`

Comment: You can reduce `.Select(selector).SelectMany(x => x)` to just `SelectMany(selector)`

Answer (score 2):

```
var n = 2;
myList.Select(s => s.Split().Where((t, i) => (i - 1) % n == 0))
```

This uses the overload of `Where` that includes the index as an argument. Note this is not robust/heavily tested/etc.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, people are quick on this one! Here's how I would implement it in a method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetEveryNthWord(string input, int n)
{
    return input.Split().Where((value, index) => (index + 1) % n == 0);
}

public static IEnumerable<string> GetEveryNthWord(IEnumerable<string> input, int n)
{
    return input.SelectMany(sentence => GetEveryNthWord(sentence, n));
}
```

And in use:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var myList = new List<string>
    {
        "Robert is a bank manager",
        "Alice is a cashier",
        "Andrew is bank customer"
    };

    var result = GetEveryNthWord(myList, 2).ToList();

    /* result
        Count = 6
            [0]: "is"
            [1]: "bank"
            [2]: "is"
            [3]: "cashier"
            [4]: "is"
            [5]: "customer"
    */
}
```